# Trying to use "android-holo-colors.com" and "AppCompat"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-holo-everywhere

I'm develiping an Android application in Eclipse, with `minSdkVersion="8"`

I want to use the theme generated by "android-holo-colors.com" but the file `values/themes_apptheme.xml` throws an error in this line:

```
 <style name="_AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that 
          matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

This is what I've done so far:

1. With `Android SDK Manager` I downloaded `Extras > Android Support Library`
2. I copied the file `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` from here: `C:\Users\Administrator\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs` to my project's library `lib`
3. I right clicked the jar in Eclipse, and then `Build Path > Add to build path`

   (These 3 steps are also in Android's documentation)
4. I downloaded the generated .zip from `android-holo-colors.com` and put all the files in their corresponding folders. Eg: I took all the xml's from the zip's drawable folder and place them in my project's drawable folder. Etc.

After doing all the above:
I'm getting the error stated at the beginning of my question.

So, the question is how do I solve this? (but previous questions can be: "am I including correctly the appcompat library?", "am I including correctly all the holo files?")

Some additional information that could be important:

1. My lib folder in the project also has android-support-v4.jar (if I right click on it, the possibility to add to build path is there, so I guess it is not in the build path)
2. I tried to use GridLayout the same way (steps 1-3) but I had a similar problem: the class GridLayout wasn't recognized/found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved...

Apparently **just putting the .jar in my project and in its buildpath wasn't enough***.

After step 3 in my question, I would add:

- In the same eclipse workspace, "import project from existing source" and select `C:\Users\Administrator\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`
- Right click in it, Properties > Android > "Is Library" must be checked (it already was after the previous step)
- In my project, which is living in the same workspace, right click, Properties > Android > Under the "Library" section, click on "Add.." and add the `android-support-v7-appcompat` project

(*) Although now is working, I'm not really sure if the step 2 and 3 in my question are necessary, because the project already "uses" the other project, which should create the same jar. If someone can clarify this last paragraph, would be great.